# How to solve node modules error related to react-tag-input package in react

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, react-dnd, server-error, yarn-v2

I am working in a team to build a react app. So after a team member made some changes and pushed, I pulled and I am getting a node modules error regarding the react-tag-input package and this package has been installed even before my recent pull.

The image attached is the error that is showing on my screen
[image]

I copied this error and pasted on google and the response was that I should change the "require" that is inside the node modules to a dynamic import but the issue is there are a lot of places where the require is used plus I am not the only one working on the project, which will be just wrong to change theirs like that even when they are not getting that error. I deleted the react-tag-input package and installed it again but still didn't work. I also deleted the node modules and installed again but nothing changed.

This is an example of what is in the file where the error is showing
[image]

I will appreciate any help I can get as this is a current project. Thank you!